# Java constructor reference assignment Vs new created object assignment

Tags: java, constructor, java-8, variable-assignment, method-reference

I met in our project following code:

```
MyInterface var = MyClass::new;
```

Is there difference with

```
MyInterface var = new MyClass();
```

Lazy?

Comment: They don’t have anything in common.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MyInterface var = new MyClass();
```

creates an instance of `MyClass` and assigns it to a variable of type `MyInterface`. This requires that `MyClass implements MyInterface` and have a no-arg constructor. The result is an instance of `MyClass` which implements `MyInterface` however it likes to.

---

```
MyInterface var = MyClass::new;
```

attemps to implement `MyInterface` ad-hoc. This requires that `MyInterface` is a *functional interface* having a single abstract method. That single abstract method must have a return type assignable from `MyClass` and a parameter list matching one of `MyClass`’ constructors.

It is analog of:

```
MyInterface var = new MyInterface() {
    public MyClass anyMethodName() {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

The result is an instance of `MyInterface` which will on invocations of its single abstract method create a new instance of `MyClass` passing all of its arguments to the constructor of `MyClass`.

---

In other words, these two constructs have nothing in common.

Comment: Looks like you are wrong about **these two constructs have nothing in common** Single difference that I cannot cast second construction result to MyClass

Comment: The second construct does not require that `MyClass` implements `MyInterface` or that there is any relationship between `MyInterface` and `MyClass`. It is not different to `Supplier<MyClass> s=MyClass::new;`. As said, *if* `MyClass` implements `MyInterface` it may do it however it wishes and implementing it by letting `MyClass` constructing other `MyClass` instances would be very uncommon. The point is, just because you can make it equivalent using several special arrangements outside of these two statements, doesn’t make these two constructs themselves equivalent.

Comment: second construction like: **new MyInterface{ public MyClass{return new Myclass()}}**

Comment: That isn’t valid Java code. But anyway, that’s a pointless discussion. A *factory which creates X* is something entirely different than *an instance of X*. That’s a fundamental difference and even if you *could* make X fulfill the same interface as the factory of X, that wouldn’t make that difference go away, just like `foo()` and `bar()` are different methods though you *could* make them do the same, they remain different.

Comment: ok. **MyInterface var = new MyInterface(){
    public MyClass anyMethodName(){
        return new MyClass();
    }
}**

Comment: So what? `MyInterface var = new MyInterface(){ public MyClass anyMethodName(){ return new MyClass(); } }` is also not the same as `MyInterface var = new MyClass();`

Comment: I think that I have understood your thought. thanks.

Comment: you can add this code to answer. I believe it will be helpful for future googlers